# systems of equations with variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the following problem in my homework

> Suppose a, b, are two constant paramaters such that the system below
>   is consistent for any values of f and g. What can you say about the
>   numbers a and b? Justify your answers. 
>   
>   x1+ax2 = f 
>   
>   bx1+ x2 = g

Am I under thinking this? Wouldn't a or b just have to be real numbers?

Answer (score 0):

To always be consistent, $\begin{bmatrix}1&a\\ b&1\end{bmatrix}$ must be invertible, i.e. nonzero determinant, so any real numbers $a,b$ with

$1-ab\neq 0$